# org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, birt, postgresql-9.2

I'm getting error:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: An exception occurred during processing. Please see the following message for details:
Cannot open the connection for the driver: org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: org.postgresql.Driver.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1245)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1224)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:96)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
```

BIRT Designer Version 4.4.1.v201408290142.

BIRT Viewer Version: 4.3.0.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.24

OS: AIX 6.1

Java 6

I have put postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar in **WEB-INF/lib** folder but exception remains. Report runs from eclipse without errors.

Can you advise?

Comment: Does BIRT use the web application's `ClassLoader` or does it have some other configuration for where to look for classes?

Answer (score 2):

May be the driver used in Designer is different from the one you copied to your viewer. In your eclipse plugin directory you will find **org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc_4.4.1.v201408290142** folder which contains the jdbc driver for your report. Copy and paste it to WEB-INF/lib folder. That would work hopefully. Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for very late answer! It seems that everything is ok, tomcat needed restart, after that everything worked fine.